# How do I get the variable out of the local scope and be able to use that variable in another view or other functions in Swift, Xcode?

Tags: php, json, swift, xcode

How do I get the variable 'model' out of the local scope and be able to use that variable in another view or other functions?

```
class LoginModel {
    
    weak var delegate: Downloadable?
    let networkModel = Network()
    func downloadLogin(parameters: [String: Any], url: String) {

        
        let request = networkModel.request(parameters: parameters, url: url)
        networkModel.response(request: request) { (data) in
            let model = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Login].self,from: data)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                print(model) //data shows
            })
            
            self.delegate?.didReceiveData(data: model)
            
        }
        print(model) //data doesn't show
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn how to work with async operations in swift... next should be helpful for start https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/managing-async-code-in-swift-d7be44cae89f

Comment: You already have a delegate protocol to pass data back. You can use that (though many of us would put that delegate call inside the dispatch to the main queue). Are you setting the delegate before calling that network method? But your print statement at the end of the method should be removed, because that’s printed after starting the request but before receiving the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't access the `model` constant is that your `model` was declared in a function with lower hierarchy than where the `print` function is located.

The way Swift variables work is that they can only be accessed on any sub-class/function/method with a lower hierarchy than itself (i.e. variables declared inside a function cannot be used outside the function itself).

To be able to access your `model` variable anywhere in every swift file in your project, you should use a global variable, which is defined by the official Swift programming guide as:

> Variables that are defined outside of any function, method, closure, or type context. Global constants and variables are always computed lazily.

Which means to say that to make `model` a global variable, you should declare it outside of your LoginModel class, or any other similar classes, functions, methods, closures, or type contexts.

If you do not need to access `model` everywhere but just need to print it, you can either move your `print` function into the `networkModel.response` function, or declare your `model` constant outside of the `networkModel.response` function.